# Defining custom keyboard shortcuts for umlauts

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, centos-7

On Windows, I used to have an AutoHotkey script for creating umlauts on my American keyboard. It looked like this:

```
!a::
send ä
return 

!o::
send ö
return

!u::
send ü
return

!+a::
send Ä
return

!+o::
send Ö
return

!+u::
send Ü
return

!s::
send ß
return
```

Is there a way to get the same thing accomplished in CentOS? I'm running GNOME on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried AutoKey? https://code.google.com/archive/p/autokey/

It's written in Python and it's scripts are also normal Python files - meaning that you can literally tweak it to infinity and inject anything you like.

Possible little caveat is that it's Python 2.7 (so you may need to play with it for a while if you need to convert it to Python 3.x or do parallel install of python27), but on the other side it's much more powerful than autohotkey

Comment: I didn't know of this project, and it didn't come up in my searches. Thanks!